# Map Fragment inflation error in an Activity that extends another Activity extending ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I know this title doesn't make sense.
The issue is I have a master activity that extends ActionBarActivity (it contains all the code that is shared in all activities); I have another activity that extends the master activity; this last activity contains a map fragment; I added all the required code and I am getting an error on the set content view.

Can someone help? What can I add to help you understand my problem?

**EDIT:**

Here's the code. I left out many things that I think are irrelevant.

MainLayoutActivity.java:

```
public class MainLayoutActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int id) {


        LinearLayout linearLayoutContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutContent);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(id, linearLayoutContent); //linrstlayoutcontent is the linearlayout that will contain the content 

    }

}
```

activity_main_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayoutMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" > 
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayoutContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/bgColor"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout> 

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/MainMenu"
        style="@style/MainMenu"
        android:background="@color/LeftMenuBackground"
        android:divider="@drawable/menu_separator" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

ClubDetailsActivity.Java

```
public class ClubDetailsActivity extends MainLayoutActivity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_club_details);
         initilizeMap();

        }


   private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {

            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            //googleMap = (My_Layout.findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                showToast("Sorry! unable to create maps");
            }
        }
    }


}
```

activity_club_details.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"  >


                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


 </LinearLayout>
```

Error:

```
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.borninteractive.fitnesstime/com.borninteractive.fitnesstime.ClubDetailsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #164: Error inflating class fragment
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #164: Error inflating class fragment
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at com.borninteractive.fitnesstime.MainLayoutActivity.setContentView(MainLayoutActivity.java:237)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at com.borninteractive.fitnesstime.ClubDetailsActivity.onCreate(ClubDetailsActivity.java:87)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): ... 11 more
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.fragment" on path: /data/app/com.borninteractive.fitnesstime-2.apk
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:558)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:649)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
05-19 19:30:50.961: E/AndroidRuntime(20934): ... 23 more
```

Thank You

Comment: Please post the stacktrace and relevant code.

Comment: @Emmanuel I posted what you requested. does this help?

Comment: Question already asked.
Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15958581/3549142

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you get ClassNotFoundException. It seems that support-library is missing in your build. Double check with this page http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res if your build path is set properly. Also check if you are not mixing fragments from support-library with native fragments.

Beside that, even if you fix `ClassNotFoundException` your app will not work. in `MainLayoutActivity setContentView` you are missing to call `super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity.xml)`;

At the moment `linearLayoutContent` will be always null because layout is not setup.

Answer (score 1):

Update your Google Play Library from your sdk manager.

```
private void checkForMap() {
    try {
        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mContext);

        // Showing status
        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status,
                    this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of
            // activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            // map = ((MapFragment)
            // getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = fm.getMap();
        }

        googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        DebugHelper.printException(exception);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Google map v2 is always extend by Fragment activity, because of in xml layout file map portion is displayed by fragment. So you should use extend the Fragment Activity for google map. Please check following link for description of google map v2:
    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start